# Magento Add to Shopping cart Issue

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

After installing an fresh magento in bluehost, I can't able to add to product is shopping cart. Shopping cart page shows empty.What is the issue?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your logs? Have you tried clearing the cache? With just the info you've given us it's really hard to pinpoint your issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: No, I am not getting any errors in error log. I have tried clearing cache and reindexing all the indexes. Just installed fresh magento and created a simple product and tried adding to cart. But the shopping cart page shows empty. If I add a product from search page, product is adding to cart. Any help please ?